# Google Sheets - finding a date within different date ranges, and then returning the relevant field

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

[image]

For example I want to see for 5th april, what zodiac is for the column sun, mercury,venus etc.
2 tabs
no idea where to start

I want to show that on 5th april on the sun column, aries is in the sun

Comment: Its time-taking to create formulas *if data is provided via screenshots* since we've to manually type the data from screenshot & then create formulas as well!  `1` However you can easily share test data via this [table generator](https://markdown-convert.com/en/tool/table). Just paste the *data rows/columns* in this generator→press enter→then copy-paste the data here in the question as a table. `2` You can also share a test sheet using this [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) & is super recommended